# Error in firebase.createUser: TypeError: cannot read property 'FirebaseAuth' of undefined

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I'm using When I try to log in or create a new user I get the following error messages

```
Error in firebase.createUser: TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirebaseAuth' of undefined
Error in firebase.login: TypeError: Cannot read property 'FirebaseAuth' of undefined
```

I have firebase.init running in my app.component.ts file.

I have been following the steps in the firebase nativescript plugin documentation for implementation.

Here's where the firebase.createUser method is called

```
    register(user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(user);
            firebase.createUser({
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            }).then(
                function (user) {
                    alert("User created, email: " + user.email)
                },
                function (errorMessage) {
                    alert("Error: " + errorMessage)
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

Here's where the firebase.login method is called

```
    login(user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(user);
            firebase.login(
                {
                    type: firebase.LoginType.PASSWORD,
                    passwordOptions: {
                        email: user.email,
                        password: user.password
                    }
                })
                .then(result => JSON.stringify(result))
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        });
    }
```

Here's my firebase.init call

```
firebase.init({
            // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
            // see their respective docs
        }).then(
            () => {
              console.log("firebase.init done");
          } ,
          error => {
              console.log(`firebase.init error: ${error}`);
          }
        );
        var listener = {
            onAuthStateChanged: function(data) {
                console.log(data.loggedIn ? "Logged in to firebase" : "Logged out from firebase");
                if (data.loggedIn) {
                    console.log("User Info", data.user);
                }
            },
            thisArg: this
        };

        // add the listener:
        firebase.addAuthStatListener(listener);

        // stop listening to auth state changes:
        firebase.removeAuthStateListener(listener);

        // check of already listening to auth state changes
        firebase.hasAuthStateListener(listener);
```

The login and createUser methods should communicate with my firebase project to create a new user or to log in an existing user.

Comment: Can you post how you are adding firebase in your project?

Comment: @AzzamAsghar, I'm using a nativescript plugin called `nativescript-plugin-firebase`

Comment: And you are using it with angular???

Comment: I guess the native dependencies are not installed, try clean build. Also did you enable firebase auth while installing the plugin, the `firebase.nativescript.json` file should have `authentication` flag set to `true`.

Comment: Did you add `/// <reference path="./node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/firebase" />` in reference.d.ts in root folder

Comment: @AzzamAsghar, yes I am. I can't see the reference.d.ts file in my root folder

Comment: @Manoj, i've just had to check and it is set to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, this problem is due to my testing my app using nativescript preview as this does not support the nativescript firebase plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For me also having same problem. 
I'm using nativescript-plugin-firebase version 10.3.3 with nativescript 6.3.0.

nativescript-plugin-firebase plugin team has proposed solution to set "analytics": true in firebase.nativescript.json.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/1431#issuecomment-543735961

But for me it didn't work